# iPhone alternate option for DatePicker

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uidatepicker

I need to select dates from a calender with a click of a button.
I tried `UIDatePicker`, but it is occupying major part of screen.
Can I have any other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally recommended to use the UIDatePicker.

I would suggest you link it to a button/tableviewcell, which when pressed presents an actionsheet with the UIDatePicker. This way will shortly occupy a large part of the screen when it's selected. In my experience there is no other way around it.